# What is the usage of adding Bootstrap css file and js files reference in angularjs application?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

It is recommended to add bootstrap references like bootstrap.css, bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap-responsive.css and associated js files for bootstrap css files in the angularjs app. What is the effect of adding these on the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.

So, using Bootstrap will definitely reduce time needed for front end development.
Just ckeck [link](http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2013/05/ive-been-doing-it-wrong-part-1-of-3/)

Answer (score 0):

- Bootstrap.css is a file you add when you are on the development phase.
- Bootstrap.min.css is a file you add when you release the software, [because it reduces the amount of data that needs to be transferred](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29), whereas the not minified version adds the readability not needed on this phase. The CSS files let you use components such as `nav`.
- The associated js files (i.e. bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.js), work the same way and they let you use javascript plug-ins such as `carousel`. These files, in any flavor, require Jquery to work.